# Bamboo NUnit Parser Could not find test result reports from a different folder

Tags: xml, nunit, bamboo

I am using 3 stages for 3 different jobs in Bamboo for a project, the first stage is to use an MSBuilder task to compile the code, then in the second stage uses NUnit Runner to run the unit tests.  Then I create a Test Report xml file.  When I try to read this file from the third stage using the NUnit Parser it gives me the error could not find test result reports.

The test results file is in the Second stages folder **C:\Users\cd\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TES-BAM-TES\TestResult.xml** but this should not matter as I should be able to read a test result xml file from anywhere but the error message is still Could not find test result reports in the **C:\Users\cd\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\TES-BAM-DT directory.**

When I complete it all in the one stage it works fine (the folder is the same) so why can it not work when I use 3 stages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that in the correct directory for the finding the TestResult.xml file is **/TestResult.xml, this worked for when using the 3 stages.